# Phase change in a light wave

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction

Is there a phase change of pi when light is reflected of off a simple plane mirror?
Do we take into account the presence of glass underneath

Comment: The phase of the electric field or the phase of the magnetic field? Is it a conductive (metallic) mirror or a dielectric mirror? Is the propagation medium air or something with a substantial non-unity $\epsilon_R$?

Comment: i) Phase of the electric field ii) Either iii) Propagation medium is air